# I work in a hospital. I want to know what we should call the proof of appointment

Tags: word-choice, names

I work in a hospital. I want to know what we should call the proof of appointment.
And I want to know the name of the place where we pay the bill after treatment.

Comment: Are you referring to your appointment in the hospital or appointment obtained by people to consult a doctor? Where I live, bills are paid at the billing counter or at the receptionist's desk.

Comment: Sounds localized  What country would this be in?

Comment: I live in Korea(south).

Comment: Reading this as a Briton and seeing "And I want to know the name of the place where we pay the bill after treatment." made me smile. Those who are British or Canadian should understand what I mean.

Comment: As an American, I also smiled at this, but wryly, understanding as I do that our friends in Great Britain and Canada do not have to pay after treatment. In the U.S., we usually call the place where we pay the bill "the cashier" (or "cashier's desk," or "cashier's office").

Comment: Is this for translation or for explaining things to English speaking foreigners in Korea? Or for what?

Comment: I cannot imagine  a world in which someone requires some officious document that counts as “proof” of an upcoming doctor’s appointment.

Answer (score 4):

In English, you'd call the proof that you have an appointment to see a doctor at a hospital clinic an [appointment slip](http://www.knox.army.mil/garrison/dhr/asd/forms/pdf_files/FK130.pdf). A "slip" is a piece of paper. The slip in the link is an official US Army document labeled *Appointment Slip*. That term should work in Korea.

Comment: *Appointment card* is commonly used in places where appointment slips are commonly on card.

Answer (score -3):

A *case paper* is something the patient may provide as proof of having an appointment to see the doctor.